# undefined method `permit' for "<p>tinymce</p>":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to implement tinyme gem and I get this error:

```
undefined method `permit` for "<p>tiny mce</p>":String
```

This is the controller:

```
def note_params
     params.require(:note).permit(:contact_id, :note)
end
```

The View:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@note) do |f| %>
                  <%= f.error_notification %>

                  <div class="form-group hidden-xs-up">
                    <label><i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</label>
                    <%= f.select :contact_id, get_contact.collect{@contact.id},{}, class:"form-control" %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group over-hide">
                    <label><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Note</label>
                    <%= text_area_tag :note, "", :class => "form-control tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 60 %>
                    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-info mt-2 float-sm-right" %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
```

How should I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Your form send the note directly as a root element and not nested in another note. This happens, because you use `text_area_tag` instead of the `text_area` form helper.

Just change:

```
<%= text_area_tag :note, "", :class => "form-control tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 60 %>
```

to

```
<%= f.text_area :note, :class => "form-control tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 60 %>
```